# Example of compiler, interpreter and both

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter

I have read enough explanation about the definition of compiler, interpreter and "things" that use both. However, I didn't find enough real-life example to differentiate those things.

Could you provide examples of them in any programming language/"things" you prefer? And please give some explanation how one differentiate from others..

Also, people say that **an interpreter evaluates source-code for immediate execution**, does that mean every compiler has interpreter to run them? Thanks..

Comment: Off-topic, since you are asking for external resources and you don't show any source code. Did you read wikipages on [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), [interpreters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29), [programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language), [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) ...

Comment: I read them already but, most people say that nowadays it's pretty hard to differentiate those words.. So, I guess with enough example one could understand the difference to the fullest..

Comment: There is a continuum between compilers & interpreters. But it is still off-topic here. You could ask a better focused question (*after* doing some research) on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ - where several questions (some of which I have answered) are related to yours here. Look inside [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/), etc...

Comment: Read also about [just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) & [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) & [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Dive into a good compiler book.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK

Programming Language is a language for creating a program, that can be [implemented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_implementation) as compiler or interpreter

[Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language) is program that translate (either from source code, byte code to another source code, byte code, or binary), for example:

- gcc
- clang
- javac
- go (compiler)

some compiler runs before the program first run, but there are some case that compiler run after program started that called [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) (just in time).

[Interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) is program that executes source code or byte code, for example:

- ruby (interpreter)
- python (interpreter)
- php (interpreter)

[Processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) is hardware that executes binary

The "things" you've mentioned maybe java (program, virtual machine) executes bytecode, mozjs (javascript engine) executes source code, but both can do JIT-compilation.